# How to find items with multiple tags on them?

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, relational-division

### Problem:

I have a table named `item_tag_assn` which maps items with tags (many-to-many association table). I need to find out items which have a set of tags applied to them. For example, if my table has following data:

```
 item_id | tag_id 
------------------
     205 | 110
     206 | 120
     207 | 130
     205 | 130
     206 | 147
     210 | 110
     205 | 152
     209 | 111
     210 | 177
     205 | 147
     212 | 110
     212 | 135
     205 | 135
     212 | 147
------------------
```

and If I am searching for

- items with tags 110, 135 and 147 then I expect items #205 and #212 in the result set.
- items with tags 110, 130, 135, 147 and 152 then I should get only item #205 because only #205 has **all of those tags** associated to it.

---

### Environment:

- PostgreSQL 9.5
- I am not allowed to add a third column to this table or create new tables altogether.

---

### Progress so far:

I have found a solution like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ita1.item_id 
FROM 
  item_tag_assn AS ita1 
  LEFT JOIN 
    item_tag_assn AS ita2 ON ita1.item_id = ita2.item_id 
  LEFT JOIN 
    item_tag_assn AS ita3 ON ita2.item_id = ita3.item_id 
GROUP BY ita1.item_id 
HAVING 
  sum((ita1.tag_id = 110 and ita2.tag_id = 135 and ita3.tag_id = 147)::integer) >= 1
```

and **it works**.

---

#### Optimization required

The association table is rather large. Joining it with itself is expensive and slows down, plus it is not very scalable. I think window functions can help but I do not know how to use them.

Is there any better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need something like this:

```
WITH search AS (
    SELECT '{110,130,135,147,152}'::int4[] as search
), searched AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT item_id,
           tag_id
      FROM item_tag_assn
      JOIN search ON (tag_id) = ANY(search)
  ORDER BY 1, 2
), aggregated AS (
    SELECT item_id,
           array_agg(tag_id) AS agg
      FROM searched
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT *
  FROM aggregated, search
 WHERE agg = search
;
```

`search` - is to set searched array (array must be presorted). 
`searched` - all rows than have searched tag 
`aggregated` - aggregated in array tag_id per item_id

You can change `agg = search` to `agg @> search` and after that you do not need presorting and  ORDER BY in `searched`.

When add your dataset from question:

```
WITH item_tag_assn AS (
      SELECT   205 as item_id, 110 as tag_id
      UNION SELECT     206 , 120
      UNION SELECT     207 , 130
      UNION SELECT     205 , 130
      UNION SELECT     206 , 147
      UNION SELECT     210 , 110
      UNION SELECT     205 , 152
      UNION SELECT     209 , 111
      UNION SELECT     210 , 177
      UNION SELECT     205 , 147
      UNION SELECT     212 , 110
      UNION SELECT     212 , 135
      UNION SELECT     205 , 135
      UNION SELECT     212 , 147
),search AS (
    SELECT '{110,130,135,147,152}'::int4[] as search
), searched AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT item_id,
           tag_id
      FROM item_tag_assn
      JOIN search ON (tag_id) = ANY(search)
  ORDER BY 1, 2
), aggregated AS (
    SELECT item_id,
           array_agg(tag_id) AS agg
      FROM searched
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT *
  FROM aggregated, search
 WHERE agg = search
;
```

Result:

```
 item_id |          agg          |        search         
---------+-----------------------+-----------------------
     205 | {110,130,135,147,152} | {110,130,135,147,152}
(1 row)
```

If change search to `'{110,135,147}'`:

```
 item_id |      agg      |    search     
---------+---------------+---------------
     212 | {110,135,147} | {110,135,147}
     205 | {110,135,147} | {110,135,147}
(2 rows)
```

For running on product you need to create index `CREATE INDEX ON item_tag_assn (tag_id);`

```
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=32.72..35.34 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.055..0.059 rows=3 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (aggregated.agg = search.search)
   CTE search
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
   CTE searched
     ->  Unique  (cost=27.73..28.55 rows=110 width=8) (actual time=0.029..0.031 rows=3 loops=1)
           ->  Sort  (cost=27.73..28.00 rows=110 width=8) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=3 loops=1)
                 Sort Key: x.item_id, x.tag_id
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10.40..24.00 rows=110 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=3 loops=1)
                       ->  CTE Scan on search search_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on x  (cost=10.40..22.88 rows=110 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=3 loops=1)
                             Recheck Cond: (tag_id = ANY (search_1.search))
                             Heap Blocks: exact=1
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i1  (cost=0.00..10.38 rows=110 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=3 loops=1)
                                   Index Cond: (tag_id = ANY (search_1.search))
   CTE aggregated
     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2.75..4.12 rows=110 width=36) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=3 loops=1)
           Group Key: searched.item_id
           ->  CTE Scan on searched  (cost=0.00..2.20 rows=110 width=8) (actual time=0.029..0.031 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on aggregated  (cost=0.00..2.20 rows=110 width=36) (actual time=0.040..0.043 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=0.02..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
         ->  CTE Scan on search  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.309 ms
 Execution time: 0.115 ms
```

Comment: For some reason, it did not work as expected :-\ It always returned a blank set.

Comment: Could you please run my test example?

Comment: The example works. I did check against my table and it worked there too. I am not sure why it did not work in the first try. I think this one is efficient enough for me. Thanks :)